# Pcrecpp multiple lines

Tags: c++, pcre

I'm using pcrecpp to match and expression in my C++ program. The relevant code is:

```
pcrecpp::RE("GET (\n*|.*)* HTTP").PartialMatch(packet, &getUrl);

cout << "GET " << getUrl << endl;
```

And the text i want to match is something like:

```
GET /subscribe?host_int=52830395&ns_map=39290872_6081712982008&ts=133411801
3 HTTP ...
```

I cannot match the whole expression between `GET` and `HTTP` because there is a new line (\n). Any idea?

Comment: It seems you try to get the URL of a HTTP `GET` request. However, there should not be any newline in the request line if you follow the HTTP specification, which leads me to think you have an invalid HTTP request.

Comment: Well, i'm getting a lot of HTTP request from a tool called [ngrep](http://ngrep.sourceforge.net/). I read that the output could be modify to be wider. I'll check out later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the documentation: http://linux.die.net/man/3/pcrecpp

Most notably look at the section titled "Passing Modifiers To The Regular Expression Engine".

You are probably interested in using the PCRE_MULTILINE and PCRE_DOTALL options. With the DOTALL option you wouldn't have to do the OR you are doing. "." would match newline characters as well.

Comment: Looks promising, i tried with `PCRE_MULTINE` but didn't work. I'll try with `PCRE_DOTALL`.